# Como forçar um PDF a ser exibido no browser

Tags: php, pdf

Tenho uma sequência de arquivos em PDF que consigo linkar normalmente, só que assim que eu clico sobre um deles ele faz download, e preciso que o PDF seja exibido no próprio browser. Já tentei usar isto no meu link mas não adiantou:

```
target="_blank"
```

Não posso deixar o usuário efetuar o download diretamente de maneira alguma. Como resolver esse problema?

Comment: Isso depende do navegador... Se você está linkando o arquivo diretamente você está dizendo para o navegador, "Aqui tem um arquivo, faça o que quiser com ele..."

Comment: mais não tem como mudar isso no caso do google chrome por uma questão de segurança nem o caminho dos pdf mostram na url e tenho que fazer visualizar na tela e não fazer o download

Comment: Sei que tem como forçar o download, mas o contrário nunca vi...

Comment: e se coloca-se em um iframe eu tentei aqui mais acho que fiz errado e que não importa como seja feito não importa mesmo só quero que exiba na tela.

Comment: Se você não quer/não pode depender do navegador para isso (ele é quem decide se força o download ou não), vai precisar converter cada página do PDF para imagem no servidor, e exibir as imagens no browser. Ou subir o arquivo para algum serviço que faz isso pra você, como o http://issuu.com/

Comment: ESquece isso pois depende da configuração do usuário. Aqui no meu pc, por exemplo, tenho o Foxit instalado. Quando clico em qualquer PDF, é feito download e abre no Foxit.. Claro que eu posso mudar e desativar esse comportamento, mas não dou a mínima e acho melhor que abra no Foxit. Não quer dizer que todos tem que fazer isso ou quem não faz esteja errado.. É apenas escolha pessoal. PAra ter noção, em outro PC, que tenho aqui, abre no browser diretamente. Enfim, essa liberdade do usuário poder escolher como usar o próprio device, vc "nunca" poderá tirar. Perceba que o "nunca" está entre aspas.

Comment: @Kirito Alguma das respostas atendeu ao que você pediu?

Comment: sim a ultima agora foi dificil mas deu certo obrigado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como já [mencionado pelo Ivan Nack](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/58969/6454), isso dependerá do navegador, há como manipular o *header* [`Content-Disposition`](http://www.iana.org/assignments/cont-disp/cont-disp.xhtml), porém dependerá de como o navegador lidará com o arquivo, pois há como configurar o navegador para sempre baixar o arquivo ou ainda, se o navegador não lida de forma nativa com PDF, usa-se *plugins* como o Adobe Reader.

Como dito pelo [bfavaretto em comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58930/como-for%C3%A7ar-um-pdf-a-ser-exibido-no-browser#comment121432_58930), uma forma de fazer isto é converter cada página do arquivo PDF em imagem e exibi-la, é assim que o Google deve fazer (*creio eu*), uma forma de fazer isto no PHP é usando a [`ImageMagick`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.imagick.php).

Segue um exemplo retirado [**daqui**](http://www.binarytides.com/convert-pdf-image-imagemagick-php/):

```
$arquivoPDF = 'demo.pdf';
$imagem = 'demo.jpg';
$img = new imagick();

$img->setResolution(200,200); // Isto é importante para dar uma saída de boa qualidade, caso contrário, o texto pode não ser claro  
$img->readImage("{$arquivoPDF}[0]"); // Lê a primeira página do PDF, o número entre [] indica a página
$img->scaleImage(800, 0);            // Reduz as dimensões
$img->setImageFormat('jpg');         // Define novo formato
$img = $img->flattenImages();        // Isso é necessário para imagens com transparência, que irá produzir um fundo branco para regiões transparentes
$img->writeImages($imagem, false);   // Salva a imagem
```

---

Uma outra alternativa, agora em Javascript, é usar um renderizador como o [**pdf.js**](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js), que não necessita de aplicativos de terceiros. Há uma [**demonstração aqui**](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html).

---

Por fim, [**há também como utilizar o visualizador do Google**](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com.br/2009/09/embeddable-google-document-viewer.html) para fazer isto o que você quer, por exemplo:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?
 url=http://infolab.stanford.edu/pub/papers/google.pdf&embedded=true"
 style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/b5wps6kx/)</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

Até onde eu sei como os PDF não são paginas da web nativas é o browser que decide o que fazer com eles.
Por isso o browser é que tem que ser configurado para abrir usando algum plugin ou o visualizador interno como no firefox por exemplo.

Ou então tenta isso

```
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header('Content-Disposition: inline; "nome_do_arquivo.pdf"');
```

Comment: ola amigo então só que os meus arquivos pdf não estão publicados eles estão em outro local fora do projeto por isso entende ele e acessado via url

Comment: Então acho que tem que configurar o browser mesmo

Answer (score 1):

Eu estava com uma dificuldade parecida segue a solução que encontrei dando as duas opções visualizar no navegador ou Download:

```
<?php
function varSet($VAR) { return isset($_GET[$VAR]) ? $_GET[$VAR] : ""; }
$action = varSet("action");
$pasta = base64_decode(varSet('pasta'));

//Lista dos arquivos que nao serão listados
$denyFiles = array(".htaccess","thumbs.db");

if ($action == "download") {
    $file = base64_decode(varSet("file"));
        header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($file)."\"");
    readfile(".$file");
    exit;
}
 if ($action == "embed") {
    $file = base64_decode(varSet("file"));
        header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
    readfile(".$file");
    exit;
}
?>
<?php
$pasta = '/arquivos';
$arquivos = "$user->cod_func".'  '.utf8_decode($_POST['select_mes']).' de '.$_POST['select_ano'].'.pdf';
$filename = 'arquivos/'.$arquivos;


if (file_exists($filename)) {
?>  
Download do Arquivo: <a href="?action=download&file=<?php echo base64_encode("$pasta/$arquivos"); ?>"><?php echo $_POST['select_mes'].' '.$_POST['select_ano']; ?></a>
<br><br>
Vizualizar: <a href="?action=embed&file=<?php echo base64_encode("$pasta/$arquivos"); ?>"><?php echo $_POST['select_mes'].' '.$_POST['select_ano']; ?></a>
<br>

<?php
} else {
    echo "Não existe holerith no mês selecionado";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Geralmente as bibliotecas de criação de PDF, como o DOMPDF e TCPDF, possuem a função que faz isso. Claro que depende muito do navegador, mas, no geral você pode usar:

Para TCPDF:

```
$pdf->Output('nomeDoArquivo.pdf', 'I');
```

Para DOMPDF:

```
$pdf->stream("nomeDoArquivo",["Attachment" => false]);
```

Assim, o documento será exibido no navegador e você decide se faz o download ou não.